# Unix command fuser not found

Tags: unix, solaris

I am on  SunOS 5.10. When I am trying to use the command `fuser`, I am getting an error that it's not found.

```
/home/user$fuser file.dat
ksh: fuser:  not found
```

But I am able to get the man page entry for `fuser`.

```
/home/user$man fuser
Reformatting page.  Please Wait... done

System Administration Commands                          fuser(1M)

NAME
     fuser - identify users of files and devices

SYNOPSIS
     /usr/sbin/fuser [-c | -d | -f]  [-nu] [-k | -s sig]  files [
     [- ] [-c | -d | -f]  [-nu] [-k | -s sig]  files] ...

DESCRIPTION
     The fuser utility displays the process IDs of the  processes
     that are using the files specified as arguments.

     Each process ID is followed by a letter code.  These  letter
     codes  are  interpreted  as follows. If the process is using
     the file as
```

Any idea how to fix this? Is this something to go with the installation?

Thanks,
Bonchi

Answer (score 3):

The manpage mentions `/usr/sbin/fuser` - is /usr/sbin/ in your PATH variable?
Can you run the command manually via `/usr/sbin/fuser`?

You can edit your .bashrc or .profile to put /usr/sbin in your path:

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin"
```

Comment: Thank you guys!! The path was not set in the .profile. I corrected it and it's working fine now.